# Join с вложенным запросом SQL

Tags: sql, inner-join

Добрый день!
Я пытаюсь джойнить две таблицы, но проблема в том, что ключевые столбцы, которые я хочу использовать (других подходящих нет) разного формата. 
Понятное дело, что можно создать отдельный процесс, где сделать новую промежуточную таблицу, в которой можно привести формат, но в таком случае таблица будет сохранена не в хранилище и затем джойнить ее с хранилищем нельзя, поскольку в ворке может не хватить места. 
Для решения этой проблемы я пытаюсь использовать вложенный запрос с left join.
Мне выдает по синтаксису ошибки.

Может быть кто-то подскажет, как это правильно делать и в чем я ошибаюсь?

Примерно часть запроса выглядит следующим образом

```
where t1.employee_rk in

left join ( 
select 
t12.employee_main_num format $11. informat $11.,
t12.functional
from imart.abm_lead_data t12 where t1.functional contains 'INST' ) t13 on (t13.employee.employee_main_num = t1.employee_rk)
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Таблицы соединяются в предложении FROM, а не WHERE.
Обратитесь к синтаксису.